# GridBagLayout not working correctly

Tags: java, swing, layout, gridbaglayout

I worked with absolute positioning (setBounds and null layout) 
and now started practicing layout managers,
this code is with gridbag layout, but few components are not being displayed, either there is some problem with the cells or something else
please help !

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
class Calculator extends JFrame
{
    JButton add,sub,mul,div,sin,cos,tan,clear,negate,inverse,zero,one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,equalTo,percentage,sqrt;
    JTextField input;
    GridBagLayout gbl;
    private void addComponent(Component component,int gridx, int gridy, int gridwidth, int gridheight,Insets insets)
    {
        add(component, new GridBagConstraints(gridx, gridy,gridwidth, gridheight, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, insets, 0,0));
    }
    Calculator()
    {
        //setSize(500,400);
        setVisible(true);
        setLayout(gbl=new GridBagLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        add= new JButton("+");
        sub= new JButton("-");
        mul= new JButton("*");
        div= new JButton("/");
        sin= new JButton("sin");
        cos= new JButton("cos");
        tan= new JButton("tan");
        clear= new JButton("C");
        negate= new JButton("neg");
        inverse= new JButton("1/x");
        zero= new JButton("0");
        one= new JButton("1");
        two= new JButton("2");
        three= new JButton("3");
        four= new JButton("4");
        five= new JButton("5");
        six= new JButton("6");
        seven= new JButton("7");
        eight= new JButton("8");
        nine= new JButton("9");
        equalTo= new JButton("=");
        percentage= new JButton("%");
        sqrt= new JButton("sqrt");
        input = new JTextField(20);

        addComponent(input,0,0,0,1,new Insets(10,10,100,4)); //tldr

        addComponent(add,0,1,1,1,new Insets(4,4,4,4));
        addComponent(sub,1,1,2,1,new Insets(4,4,4,4));
        addComponent(mul,2,1,3,1,new Insets(4,4,4,4)); // this is not displayed
        addComponent(div,3,1,4,1,new Insets(4,4,4,4));

        addComponent(sin,0,2,1,2,new Insets(4,4,4,4));
        addComponent(cos,1,2,2,2,new Insets(4,4,4,4));
        addComponent(tan,2,2,3,2,new Insets(4,4,4,4)); // this is not displayed
        addComponent(clear,3,2,4,2,new Insets(4,4,4,4));

        addComponent(negate,0,3,1,3,new Insets(4,4,4,4)); // these 4 are not visible
        addComponent(inverse,1,3,2,3,new Insets(4,4,4,4));
        addComponent(zero,2,3,3,3,new Insets(4,4,4,4));
        addComponent(one,3,3,4,3,new Insets(4,4,4,4));
        pack();
    }
    public static void main(String...args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new Calculator();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, well done for having a go at using layouts!

The thing that jumps out at me immediately is the values are passing to `gridwidth` and `gridheight`

```
addComponent(add,0,1,1,1,new Insets(4,4,4,4));
addComponent(sub,1,1,2,1,new Insets(4,4,4,4));
addComponent(mul,2,1,3,1,new Insets(4,4,4,4)); // this is not displayed
addComponent(div,3,1,4,1,new Insets(4,4,4,4));
```

Basically this is saying, add `add` to grid x/y position 0x1, with a `gridwidth`/`gridheight` of `1x1`, good so far.

Then add `sub` at x/y position `1x1` with a `gridwidth`/`gridheight` of `1x2`, okay...

Then add `mul` at x/y position `2x1` with a `gridwidth`/`gridheight` of `1x3`, now we start running into problems...Basically, `sub` is actually expending into our cell, covering part of us up!

`gridwidth` and `gridheight` allow you to define how many cells the component will expand into, most of the time, you want this to be `1x1`

Once I corrected all the `gridwidth` and `gridheight` values to `1x1`, I was able to get this

[image]

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

class Calculator extends JFrame {

    JButton add, sub, mul, div, sin, cos, tan, clear, negate, inverse, zero, one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, equalTo, percentage, sqrt;
    JTextField input;
    GridBagLayout gbl;

    private void addComponent(Component component, int gridx, int gridy, int gridwidth, int gridheight, Insets insets) {
        add(component, new GridBagConstraints(gridx, gridy, gridwidth, gridheight, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, insets, 0, 0));
    }

    Calculator() {
        //setSize(500,400);
        setLayout(gbl = new GridBagLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        add = new JButton("+");
        sub = new JButton("-");
        mul = new JButton("*");
        div = new JButton("/");
        sin = new JButton("sin");
        cos = new JButton("cos");
        tan = new JButton("tan");
        clear = new JButton("C");
        negate = new JButton("neg");
        inverse = new JButton("1/x");
        zero = new JButton("0");
        one = new JButton("1");
        two = new JButton("2");
        three = new JButton("3");
        four = new JButton("4");
        five = new JButton("5");
        six = new JButton("6");
        seven = new JButton("7");
        eight = new JButton("8");
        nine = new JButton("9");
        equalTo = new JButton("=");
        percentage = new JButton("%");
        sqrt = new JButton("sqrt");
        input = new JTextField(20);

        addComponent(input, 0, 0, 0, 1, new Insets(10, 10, 100, 4)); //tldr

        addComponent(add, 0, 1, 1, 1, new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4));
        addComponent(sub, 1, 1, 1, 1, new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4));
        addComponent(mul, 2, 1, 1, 1, new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4)); // this is not displayed
        addComponent(div, 3, 1, 1, 1, new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4));

        addComponent(sin, 0, 2, 1, 1, new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4));
        addComponent(cos, 1, 2, 1, 1, new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4));
        addComponent(tan, 2, 2, 1, 1, new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4)); // this is not displayed
        addComponent(clear, 3, 2, 1, 1, new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4));

        addComponent(negate, 0, 3, 1, 1, new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4)); // these 4 are not visible
        addComponent(inverse, 1, 3, 1, 1, new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4));
        addComponent(zero, 2, 3, 1, 1, new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4));
        addComponent(one, 3, 3, 1, 1, new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4));
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Calculator();
            }

        });
    }

}
```

Comment: i was taking the gridwidth, gridheight as absolute, rather than positional (relative) which was the mistake